# Segoe Ui not working using css

Tags: css, font-face

Here is what I am doing

```
@font-face{
font-family:'segoe';
src:url('font\Segoe.ttf');
font-wight:normal;
font-style:normal;


h2{
font-family:segoe;

 }
```

Comment: `font-wight:normal;` `e` is missing

Comment: @abhitalks, the name is just a name; you could just as well use `foobar` as the font family name here.

Comment: There are many errors in the code that prevent it from doing anything (missing `}` being the most serious). But the key question is: what are you trying to accomplish? To use Segoe UI in your own computer? You don’t normally need `@font-face` for that. To use Segoe UI on web pages as a downloadable font? That would be illegal, unless the copyright holder just changed their policy.

Comment: Ahhh yes @Jukka. I completely ignored `@font-face` like an idiot.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have a copyrights for `Segoe UI` font. To use this font you have to purchase a license from Microsoft. However I've found many glitched on your posted code.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    src: url('fonts/segoeui.eot');
    src: url('fonts/segoeui.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/segoeui.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/segoeui.svg#SegoeUI') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

h2{ font-family: "Segoe UI"; font-weight: lighter; }
```

Comment: Yeah sorry i actually miss typed here....And yes i know that the this font is a copyrighted entity but still i just want to use it for my college little project....And after trying all the methods you people posted,i cant render this font on the browser :( and i just want a simple way out of it

Answer (score 1):

Setting aside the point Kheema makes about [Segoe UI being a commercial font with usage restrictions forbidding what you're doing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/3184/3882), the `@font-face` declaration defines the font file to be used for a specific name, style and weight of a font.

There are a few minor issues in your code:

1. The `@font-face` declaration is missing its closing brace
2. The `font-weight` property is spelled wrong.
3. The URL for the font uses backslashes (`\`) instead of forward slashes (`/`) for the path (which isn't valid CSS)
4. By default, h2 elements are set in bold (but you defined the font for normal weight only). So you need to either add `font-weight: normal` to the h2 declaration or change the `font-weight` in the font declaration above to `bold`. Which is right depends on whether or not the TTF file you're pointing to is bold or regular weight.
5. TTF fonts are [not fully supported in `@font-face` on IE](http://caniuse.com/ttf) due to font licensing issues.